# regex for hh:mm and h:mm

Tags: c++, regex

I am having a problem submitting this solution to an online judge; this is the problem statement: https://justpaste.it/590vo

This is the code developed so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
//#include <sstream>
#include <string>
//#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    string str;
    regex b("(^|[^:\\d])(([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d)($|[^:\\d]|\\d?\\d:\\d\\d)");
    smatch m;
    while (getline(cin, str)) {
        auto pos = str.cbegin();
        while (regex_search(pos, str.cend(), m, b)) {
            cout << m[2] << endl;;
            pos = m[2].second;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives wrong answer for test case 5, which is not visible, what might be the problem?

Comment: You might try throwing this into https://regex101.com/ and see if you can break it.

Comment: Sidenote: I recommend that you use raw string literals when constructing `regex`s to save yourself all the double backslashes everywhere.

Comment: As is usually the case, using a regular expression here is overkill. There are only 4 or 5 characters to examine, and parsing them directly is straightforward.

Comment: yes, but it is required by the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in the requirements that you linked to that says that the solution must use a regular expression.

Comment: yes, but told so!

Comment: `It gives wrong answer for test case 5, which is not visible`  Can you add all the test cases to the question?

Comment: Which is "test case 5"? You should contain *all relevant details* for your question within the text, not within some 3rd-party websites, since those links are likely to go dead. Also, on the linked page, I can also not find 5 test cases. As such, I vote to close this question, until missing details are filled in.

Comment: On Stack Overflow (actually, all of the Stack Exchange Network), questions must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which *require* users to go to off-site links in order to have the context needed to answer are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, if the off-site information is moved into the question. Note that if that content isn't yours, you need to comply with the [referencing requirements](/help/referencing) in addition to any copyright concerns.

Comment: When you post a question that has peculiar requirements (such as requiring a regular expression for something as simple as this) you really should say so in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed single digits for minutes like 1 minute past 15 `15:1`. Try:

```
"(^|[^:\\d])(([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):(\\d|[0-5]\d))([^:\\d]|$)"
```

But just use `[0-9]` and save from typing `\\\\\\`

```
"(^|[^:0-9])(([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))([^:0-9]|$)"
```

You can shorten a bit:

```
"(^|[^:0-9])(([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]?[0-9])([^:[0-9]]|$)"
```

Comment: None worked, actually, it fails test 3 now

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance it looks pretty correct, the only thing I can identify is first group

```
(^|[^:\\d])
```

1. minor: looks like left part is not needed, because it is not digit and not colon, so covered by right part
2. another suggestion: probably you shouldn’t assume any non-digit and non-colon as separator. To avoid parsing time from “$3:30” or “-8:59” or “abc1:33dd“.
   Maybe you can try whitespaces instead:

```
    (^|\\s)
```

Comment: didn't work, it doesn't produce correct results

Comment: my bad, check updated answer

Comment: actually it got me wrong answer 2, not instead of 5!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just wonder did you try without first and/or last group?

```
(([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d)
```

maybe your tests are expecting solution to parse also things like:

8**8:35**

**13:55**5

Comment: Well, your regex doesn't print those!

Comment: My regex seems to be fine [link](https://regex101.com/r/JoQhLx/3) (beware double backslash means single on _regex101_). It is just not compatible with your code (groups amount changed) so you need to adopt it.